# 'strided_slice_19' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, tpu

I tried to use keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator on TPU,but i get this error from the first epoch.the same code work with jupyter notebook but take hours for trainig.

My MODEL:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(220))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(120))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Optimizer

```py
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

model.compile(
      optimizer=opt,
      loss='categorical_crossentropy',
      metrics=['acc'])
```

Convert Keras to TPU

```py
try:
    device_name = os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
    TPU_ADDRESS = 'grpc://' + device_name
    print('Found TPU at: {}'.format(TPU_ADDRESS))

except KeyError:
    print('TPU not found')
tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
        tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_ADDRESS)))
```

ImageDataGenerator

```py
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')#binary ,categorical

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')
```

Model Fit

```py
model_fit=tpu_model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,

    epochs=50,
    steps_per_epoch=60, 

)
```

I get this error

> Epoch 1/50 15/33 [============>.................] - ETA: 8s - loss:
>   4.7722 - acc: 0.0083INFO:tensorflow:New input shapes; (re-)compiling: mode=train (# of cores 8), [TensorSpec(shape=(0,), dtype=tf.int32,
>   name='core_id_60'), TensorSpec(shape=(0, 128, 128, 3),
>   dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_3_input_20'), TensorSpec(shape=(0,
>   120), dtype=tf.float32, name='activation_13_target_30')]
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)    1658
>   try:
>   -> 1659     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)    1660   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
>
> InvalidArgumentError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for
>   'strided_slice_19' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0], [1],
>   [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] =
>   <1>, input[3] = <1>.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last) 17 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)    1660
>   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:    1661     # Convert to
>   ValueError for backwards compatibility.
>   -> 1662     raise ValueError(str(e))    1663     1664   return c_op
>
> ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for
>   'strided_slice_19' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0], [1],
>   [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] =
>   <1>, input[3] = <1>.